# nodejs weird if case

Tags: node.js, serial-port

I'm totally new to nodejs and I have been trying to communicate arduino and node app.My node code listens to serial port and sends datas to page.Everything is ok but a weird case has occured.

```
var cleanData = ''; // this stores the clean data
var readData = '';  // this stores the buffer
sp.on("open", function () {
      console.log('open serial communication');
      });
         // Listens to incoming data
sp.on('data', function (data) { // call back when data is received
        readData += data.toString(); // append data to buffer
        // as clean data. Then clear the buffer. 
        if (readData.indexOf('B') >= 0){
            cleanData = readData.substring(readData.indexOf('B')+1,readData.length);
            console.log(cleanData);
            readData = '';

            //io.sockets.emit('pulse', cleanData);
        }

    });
```

Datas that are starting with 'B' are supposed to be printed but when i run the code,I see

```
226
Q26
226
Q252

207
Q498
```

like these.Why datas with 'Q' get printed?

Comment: If the buffer you receive contains `B226\nQ26\n`, you'll print `226\nQ26\n`...?

Comment: Ok.How can i get only 226?

Comment: or `readData += data.toString();`buffer turns a simple string?Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split on line feed too, something like;

```
sp.on('data', function (data) {          // Call back when data is received

    readData += data.toString();         // Append data to buffer

    while(readData.indexOf('\n') > 0) {  // Process all full rows

      // Get everything before the line feed
      var cleanData = readData.substring(0, readData.indexOf('\n'));

      // ...and remove what we just extracted from the read buffer
      readData = readData.substring(readData.indexOf('\n') + 1, readData.length);

      // If it contains a B, well... you know what to do
      if(cleanData.indexOf('B') > 0) {
        console.log(cleanData);
        //io.sockets.emit('pulse', cleanData);
      }
    }
});
```